# Critical point of $x\arctan(x)$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, optimization, inverse

I am trying to prove that $f(x) = x \arctan(x)$ has a global minimum at $x=0$ (obvious from the plot of the function). I know that: $$f'(x) = \arctan(x) + x \arctan'(x) = \arctan(x) + \frac{x}{1+x^2}.$$

The first order condition is $f'(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \arctan(x) + \frac{x}{1+x^2} = 0$.

How can I show that $x=0$ is a critical point of $f(x)$?

Comment: Did you compute $f'(0)$?

Comment: I did, but only because I learned from the plot that x=0 is the critical point. I was not able to solve the first order condition for x.

Comment: And $f''(0)=2>0$ so it is local minumum by second derivative test.

Comment: @BobDobbs I know, but that assumes I already know x=0 is the critical point. Without plotting f(x), how could I have found that x=0 is the critical point? I was not able to solve the first order condition for x.

Comment: We can look at the function values and sketch the graph. What is wrong with using derivative tests? @Pedro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need Calculus at all to solve this problem. If $x>0$, then $f(x)=x\arctan(x)>0$, and, if $x<0$, then $f(x)=x\arctan(x)>0$ too. On the other hand, $f(0)=0$. Therefore, $f$ has a global minimum at $0$.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.